# Firefox displaying padding differently to all other browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a tab that has two borders on either side, the borders must fill the toolbar they are within and to achieve this I have used padding. In Chrome, IE, etc. the top and bottom padding must be set at 9px to fill the toolbar, however in Firefox they must be at 4px.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNHpz/) with a mockup of the toolbar added.

The markup is pretty simple;

```
<a href="Discover">
  <span class="navButton">
    Discover
  </span>
</a>
```

I have removed transitions and other unneeded styles from the css;

```
.navButton {width:50px; border-right-color:#171717; 
            border-right-width:1px; border-right-style:solid;
            position:relative; 
            padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; 
            padding-top:9px; padding-bottom:9px;
           }
```

Comment: Do you *want* the padding at 9px and 4px ("the top and bottom padding must be set .. however in Firefox .. must be [set] .."), respectively, or are they *rendering* as 9px and 4px?

Comment: Also, just stylistically, you'll save a lot of lines of code using shorthand CSS. border: 1px solid #171717; padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px; Just a tip :)

Comment: @SeanThompson I did't know there was a short hand border property but I shall now use it thanks!

Comment: @pst I would keep the padding at 9px as that works in all browsers but FF but need to find out why it is rendering differently in FF. I have inspected the element in FF and it says padding is 9px and I haven't noticed any different styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:inline-block` would be quite appropriate here (at least a reasonable suggestion without seeing the rest of the code). You'll also need to drop the width declaration as your tab caption is wider than 50px - the reason you can't notice it now is because elements rendered inline (including `<span>` with default `display` property) can't have dimensions applied to them.

Works fine [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/UkgwS/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a fiddle and it works fine now. I have set it to `display: inline-block` and changed paddings and positions around.

Answer (score -1):

Span is an *inline*-element by default and maybe handles the padding completely different than a block-element. Try setting:

```
.navButton {
    display: block;
}
```

and check the results.

In general, you should include a CSS reset script (Google for it).

Comment: That does not work, it just takes the tab out of the toolbar. The tab must be an inline element for it to show properly in the toolbar. Inline-block does not work either and creates a strange mess of borders in ALL browsers

Comment: Oh and a css reset script does nothing and kind of messes up a few minor things on other parts so i'll leave it.